# How to resize flalign*, so I can shrink some rows little bit?

Tags: align

I want to display several formulas in `flalign*`. But some lines a bit long, so I have to write a tiny part in the next line.

```
 \begin{footnotesize}
 \begin{flalign*}
  & \{ \texttt{abs(A,abs(B,app($X$,B)))}  =  \texttt{abs(C,abs(D,app(D,$X$)))} \}  &  \texttt{start} \\  
   &  \,\, , \{ \} & \\  want add this line to previous line

 \end{flalign*}
 \end{footnotesize}
```

How can merge the first and the second line by shrinking it slightly?
I tried `\resizebox`, but having error.

Comment: are you sure you want `flalign` here? almost all of your input is in `\texttt` so set as text not math

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes, I better use math, because I have some math symbols. I did not show all formulas here.

Comment: try `\begin{flalign*}
  & \{ \texttt{abs(A,abs(B,app($X$,B)))}  =  \texttt{abs(C,abs(D,app(D,$X$)))} \}  
                    &  \texttt{start}  
                        &    \\
  &  \,\, , \{ \}   &   want add this line to previous line 
                        &
 \end{flalign*}`.

Comment: but as with your `$X$` you could access math in some other structure, `flalign` just looks the wrong place to start really here but please fix your example so that it demonstrates the issue and examples can be tested for example it should be  a complete document (not least to see the page size so it's possible to see what the text has to fit in to)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle you are right. I used tabular and it looks much better now. I should not have used flalign. Thx :)